# I can't use the command ftp

Tags: yum, ftp

When I try to install ftp:

```
$ sudo yum install ftp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package ftp available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

When I try to connect to my ftp:

```
$ ftp 10.2.4.202
-bash: ftp: command not found
```

Searching for ftp via `yum`:

```
$ sudo yum search ftp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
====================================================================== N/S Matched: ftp ======================================================================
curl.x86_64 : A utility for getting files from remote servers (FTP, HTTP, and others)
wget.x86_64 : A utility for retrieving files using the HTTP or FTP protocols

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Trying the recommended following: yum install lftp, list *ftp*, install ncftp (same results):

```
$ sudo yum install lftp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package lftp available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Trying `lftp`:

```
$ lftp 10.2.4.202
-bash: lftp: command not found
```

Output of `yum repolist`:

```
$ sudo yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                repo name                         status
CactiEZ                CactiUsers Cactiez Repo           30
pgdg93                 PostgreSQL 9.3 6 - x86_64         195
repolist: 225
```

Comment: az93 since yesterday you have shown no search skills at all a simple http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ftp+client+centos would give you the answer on the second link.  please start thinking instead of only relying on other's skill. Please reinstall your OS or try to express your issue being precise refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Kiwy >> I tried this. It doesn't work as I said before

Comment: What is your Linux distribution? If it is RHEL, CentOS, or Fedora, there _should_ be an "ftp" RPM with a `ftp` command. It's not necessarily the most user-friendly choice, but it's there. Something _else_ is wrong on your system.

Comment: It's CentOS 6.3

Comment: Does `apropos ftp`

Comment: command not found

Comment: This sounds like you're having an issue connecting to the network. Can you confirm that you can ping 8.8.8.8. If that works then try pinging www.google.com. If that doesn't work then your network setup isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Yes I can ping 8.8.8.8, google, no problem.

Comment: I'm a little tempted to reopen this, because the issue isn't really with FTP per se. It's that the system is very messed up. You should have at least a centos repository enabled. No wonder yum can't find anything -- all it has are the postgresql repo and this cactus thing.

Answer (score 4):

The output of this command sequence:

```
$ sudo yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                repo name                         status
CactiEZ                CactiUsers Cactiez Repo           30
pgdg93                 PostgreSQL 9.3 6 - x86_64         195
repolist: 225
```

Would seem to indicate that your YUM installation and repositories is severely damaged. To debug this further I'd need to see what repository files you actually do have in your `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory.

The standard YUM repository .repo files should be owned by a package called `centos-release-*`. You can confirm like so:

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

If this directory has been damaged, you could manually re-add these files or re-install using the appropriate CentOS `.rpm` file.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps below to configure your FTP server:

## First Solution:

### 1. Install vsftpd

```
$ sudo yum -y update
```

Then install vsftpd server (very secure FTP daemon) and any required packages:

```
$ yum -y install vsftpd
```

### 2. Configure vsftpd

Open the file below with any TextEditor you're comfortable with. My choice is always `vi` or `vim`.

```
$ vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

You need do disallow unidentified users:

`anonymous_enable=NO`

Allow local users:

`local_enable=YES`

If you wanna let local users write to a directory, use:

`write_enable=YES`

When the line below is set to Yes, all the local users will be jailed within their chroot and will be denied access to any other part of the server:

`chroot_local_user=YES`

Great, you can now restart the service to apply changes:

```
$ service vsftpd restart     /*CentOS 6*/
$ chkconfig vsftpd on        /*To set the service to start at boot*/

OR

$ systemctl restart vsftpd   /*CentOS 7*/
$ systemctl enable vsftpd    /*To set the service to start at boot*/
```

**N.B.** If you're on CentOS 7, you need to allow it through the firewall:

```
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=21/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

**D.M.** FTP is inertially insecure, so consider using it over SSL/TLS via sFTP command, unless you really have to use FTP.

## Second Solution:

### If the above instruction couldn't help, do the following:

On 64-bit:

```
wget -c http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ftp-0.17-51.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

On 32-bit:

```
wget -c http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/ftp-0.17-51.1.el6.i686.rpm
```

Then, install it:

```
rpm -ivh ftp-0.17-51.1.el6.x86_64.rpm     /*64-bit*/

OR

rpm -ivh ftp-0.17-51.1.el6.i686.rpm       /*32-bit*/
```

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

## Install FTP client for CentOS 7:

```
# wget -c http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ftp-0.17-54.el6.x86_64.rpm
# rpm -ivh ftp-0.17-54.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

## Usage:

```
# ftp -h

        Usage: { ftp | pftp } [-Apinegvtd] [hostname]
           -A: enable active mode
           -p: enable passive mode (default for ftp and pftp)
           -i: turn off prompting during mget
           -n: inhibit auto-login
           -e: disable readline support, if present
           -g: disable filename globbing
           -m: don't force data channel interface to the same as control channel
           -v: verbose mode
           -t: enable packet tracing [nonfunctional]
           -d: enable debugging
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ftp clients. To get a list of them, do

```
yum list \*ftp\*
```

Two common ones are `lftp` and `ncftp`. TO install either of them, do

```
yum install ncftp
```

or

```
yum install lftp
```

Then use whichever one you installed, by using the command `lftp` or `ncftp` instead of just `ftp`.

Comment: I tried all of these. Always same result "Error: Nothing to do"

Comment: What is your `$PATH`?

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: What happens if you type `ncftp`?

Comment: command not found

Comment: next test: `whereis ncftp`

Comment: rroot@localhost ~]# whereis ncftp
ncftp:

Comment: that's all ....

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how you've managed to install the package and still not be able to use it.

Comment: Ok thx for your help.

Answer (score -1):

There is no rpm package called ftp. To see all packages that contain ftp you type :

```
yum search ftp
```

If you want a ftp client you could use lftp. To install it:

```
yum install lftp
```

Then use it :

```
lftp 10.2.4.202
```

Comment: See the [edit]. It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install FTP. To install ftp , run the below command.

```
# yum -y install ftp
```

For more please click [here](http://blog.eduguru.in/centos-ftp-command-not-found-linux-ftp-install/).

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use

```
$:yum search ftp
```

it will show you all the packages containing ftp word. I believe that the one you have to install is

```
yum install ftp.x86_64
```

good luck!

Comment: How about reading the question, especially the part that says _"Searching for ftp via `yum`"_...